# AAPT: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
  C:\Users\Hadi\AndroidStudioProjects\LightRecorder\app\src\main\res\values\ids.xml:3:5-50: AAPT: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
9 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 8 up-to-date
```

Comment: Im so sorry . Im very sad . So I forgot to say Hello . Hello and Thank alot my buddies

Answer (score 2):

I find it . When I upgrade my android studio and something , I had that error . I searched a lot and finally I find it . just I had to change ids in values

```
<resources>
<item name="name" type="id">ID</item>
```

to

```
<resources>
<item name="ID" type="id"/>
```

After that everything was trued
I hope that it used for you

Comment: had the same issue fixed by this......doesn't know why this happened though